# Implementation of ls | wc -l

Tags: exec

The following code implements:

```
ls | wc -l
```

**code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int pfds[2];

    pipe(pfds);

    if (!fork()) {
        close(1);       /* close normal stdout */
        dup(pfds[1]);   /* make stdout same as pfds[1] */
        close(pfds[0]); /* we don't need this */
        execlp("ls", "ls", NULL);
    } else {
        close(0);       /* close normal stdin */
        dup(pfds[0]);   /* make stdin same as pfds[0] */
        close(pfds[1]); /* we don't need this */
        execlp("wc", "wc", "-l", NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

in `execlp("ls", "ls", NULL);`why we are replacing ls by ls? what this line is trying to implement?

Comment: Are you trying to let us answer some homework here ? because between your previous question and this one, I find it really strange...

Comment: This is however only a implementation of a pipe, because you call ls and wc from C.

Answer (score 2):

The prototype for `execlp()` on my Arch linux box:

```
int execlp(const char *file, const char *arg, ...);
```

You aren't "replacing 'ls' by 'ls'". The first instance of "ls" is the file to exec, apparently in the current working directory. The second instance of "ls" will become the value of `argv[0]` according to the exec man page.

You'll recall that C programs under Unix and Linux have a conventional entry point of `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. `argv` is an a array of pointers, and the first points (index 0) will point to a string "ls".

The value of this comes from being able to change program behavior based on the value of `argv[0]`. Traditionally, `vi` and `ex` file names were hard-linked to the same data.  If exec'ed at `vi`, the program was a full-screen editor. Exec'ed as `ex`, it changed behavior and ran as a line editor. A lot of other executables work the same way.

This is an example of synergy between Unix conventional entry point and hard and soft links.

Comment: `busybox` is an example that invokes a different script according to the name it is invoked with. You can `execlp("busybox", "ls", NULL);` to invoke it as `ls`, and `execlp("busybox", "wc", NULL);` to invoke it as `wc`.